# How to add inertia to animations tracking mouse move?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to rotate a triangle around an origin point using mouseMove event.
I'm getting the *touch start point* and the *current touch point* using `touchstart` and `touchmove` events, then I'm finding the angle of direction easily using:

```
alpha = y2 - y1 / x2 - x1;     // alpha is the tangent of the angle
beta= atan(alpha);      // beta is the angle in radians
```

Then I'm rotating the element in `PIXI`:

```
function animTriangle (beta) {

  // initially clear the previous shape
  myTriangle.clear();


  // draw a new shape in new positions
  myTriangle.beginFill(0x000000, 0.1);
  myTriangle.moveTo(origin.x, origin.y);
  myTriangle.lineTo(origin.x - 100, 0);
  myTriangle.lineTo(origin.x + 100, 0);
  myTriangle.lineTo(origin.x, origin.y);
  myTriangle.endFill();
  myTriangle.rotation = beta;

}
```

I'm managing my paintings using `RequestAnimationFrame` loop.

The problem is the animation is choppy and I need inertia in rotation. How could fix this function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Inertia, acceleration, and drag**

A method I use is to create a chasing value that chases the desired value using a  deltaV that simulates acceleration and drag (resistance) values. Note this is a simple simulation.

**Step by step**

Defining required values

```
var rotate = ?; // the value input by the user
var rotateChase; // this is the chasing value representing the displayed control
var rotateDelta; // this is the change in chase per frame
const rotateDrag = 0.4; // this is the friction or drag
const rotateAcceleration = 0.9; // this is how quickly the display responds
```

The drag is a value greater than 0 and <= 1 and is more like a damping spring in function. Values less than 0.5 provide a smooth stop to the counting value. Values >= 0.5 cause the chase value to bounce around the required value, as the drag value moves towards 1 the bounce become more and more pronounced.

The acceleration value is a range greater than 0 and <= 1. This is how responsive to change the chase value is. Low values will make the control seem sluggish or heavy. Higher values make the chase quick to respond and seem light to the touch.

Drag and Acceleration both effect each other. 
For

- quick light response `accel = 0.9`, `drag = 0.49`
- light slow response `accel = 0.1`, `drag = 0.49`
- heavy slow response `accel = 0.02`, `drag = 0.49`
- hard springy response `accel = 0.7`, `drag = 0.7`
- slow springy response `accel = 0.1`, `drag = 0.7`

**Updating**

Then once a frame, accelerate towards the input value by adding to deltaV,

```
rotateDelta += (rotate - rotateChase) * rotateAcceleration;
```

Add drag to the delta by reducing its mangitude.

```
rotateDelta *= rotateDrag;
```

Then add the deltaV to the chasing value,

```
rotateChase += rotateDelta;
```

Now it is ready to display the chasing value

```
myTriangle.rotation = rotateChase;
```

**Adding boundaries**

That is an unbound chaser. To set bounds to the value needs some extra code. First describe the bounds by setting min and max values.

```
var rotateMin = 0;
var rotateMax = Math.PI*2;
```

Then describe the behaviour if the value crosses the bounds by defining the reflection or bounce. 0 makes it stop dead at the bounds, < 0 and  >= -1 will give a small bounce from the ends. Other values create interesting FX

```
var rotateReflect = -0.5;
```

and then the code to control that behaviour

```
if (rotateChase < rotateMin) { 
   rotateChase = rotateMin;  // set to the min val
   if(rotateDelta < 0){      // only if delta is negative
       rotateDelta *= rotateReflect;
   }
}else
if (rotateChase > rotateMax) {
   rotateChase = rotateMax;  // set to the max
   if(rotateDelta > 0){      // only if delta is positive
       rotateDelta *= rotateReflect;
   }
}
```

**Display and use**

You are now just left with the choice of which value to use as the input of the control. `rotateChase` and `rotate` can both be used but `rotateChase` can take a little time to settle down to. What I do is get a rounded value from the `rotateChase` value which removes the fine detail of the chase.

For example if the control is for a volume

```
device.volume = Number(rotateChase.toFixed(3));
```

**Making it easy**

That all seams like a lot of work for one value. But we are programmers and inherently lazy, so lets compartmentalise it into a simple inertia class

```
// Define a Inertia object. Set Answer for details.
// Has methods 
// update(input); Called once pre animation frame with input being the value to chase
// setValue(input); Hard sets the chasing value. Not drag or inertia
// Has properties
// value;  The chasing value bounds checked
function Inertia (min, max, acceleration, drag, reflect) {
    // some may question why the constants, why not use the closure on arguments
    // Reason: Some JS environments will fail to optimise code if the input
    //         arguments change. It may be tempting to extend this Object to 
    //         change the min, max or others. I put this here to highlight the
    //         fact that argument closure variables should not be modified
    //         if performance is important.
    const ac = acceleration;  // set constants
    const dr = drag;
    const minV = min;
    const maxV = max;
    const ref = -Math.abs(reflect); // ensure a negative. Why? because I always forget this is a negative.
    this.value = min;
    var delta = 0;

    this.update = function (input) {
         delta += (input - this.value) * ac;
         delta *= dr;
         this.value += delta;
         if (this.value < minV) {
             this.value = minV;
             if(delta < 0){
                 delta *= ref;
             }
         } else
         if (this.value > maxV) {
             this.value = maxV;
             if(delta > 0){
                 delta *= ref;
             }
         }
         return this.value;
     };
     // this move the value to the required value without any inertial or drag
     // is bound checked
     this.setValue = function (input) {
         delta = 0;
         this.value = Math.min(maxV, Math.min(minV, input));
         return this.value;
     }
 }
```

To use the code above

```
// in init
var rotater = new Inertia(0, Math.PI*2, 0.9, 0.4, -0.1);

// in the animation frame
myTriange = rotater.update(beta);
```

**UPDATE**

I have added some code to show the various settings and how they effect inertia. The code is not intended as an example of code style or DOM interfacing best practice, for it falls very far short on both counts. It uses the Inertia object I presented above. You can find that object at the top of the demo code.

The demo is best viewed **Full Screen**

```js
//------------------------------------------------------
// Function from answer Inertia 
// Define a Inertia object. Set Answer for details.
// Has methods 
// update(input); Called once pre animation frame with input being the value to chase
// set(input); Hard sets the chasing value. Not drag or inertia
// Has properties
// value;  The chasing value bounds checked
function Inertia (min, max, acceleration, drag, reflect) {
    // some may question why the constants, why not use the closure on arguments
    // Reason: Some JS environments will fail to optimise code if the input
    //         arguments change. It may be tempting to extend this Object to 
    //         change the min, max or others. I put this here to highlight the
    //         fact that argument closure variables should not be modified
    //         if performance is important.
    const ac = acceleration;  // set constants
    const dr = drag;
    const minV = min;
    const maxV = max;
    const ref = -Math.abs(reflect); // ensure a negative. Why? because I always forget this is a negative.
    this.value = min;
    this.quiet = true;
    var delta = 0;

    this.update = function (input) {
         delta += (input - this.value) * ac;
         delta *= dr;
         this.value += delta;
         if (this.value < minV) {
             this.value = minV;
             if(delta < 0){
                delta *= ref;
             }
         } else
         if (this.value > maxV) {
             this.value = maxV;
             if(delta > 0){
                 delta *= ref;
             }
         }
         if(Math.abs(delta) < (maxV-minV)*0.001 && Math.abs(this.value-input) < 0.1 ){
             this.quiet = true;
         }else{
             this.quiet = false;
         }
         return this.value;
     };
     // this move the value to the required value without any inertial or drag
     // is bound checked
     this.setValue =  function (input) {
         delta = 0;
         this.quiet = true;
         this.value = Math.min(maxV, Math.max(minV, input));
         return this.value;
     }
 }
// End of answer
//--------------------------------------------------------







// All the following code is not part of the answer.
// I have not formatted, commented, and thoroughly tested it


/** MouseFullDemo.js begin **/
var canvasMouseCallBack = undefined;  // if needed
function createMouse(element){
    var demoMouse = (function(){
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false,
            lx:0,ly:0,
            interfaceId : 0, buttonLastRaw : 0,  buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,  // mouse is over the element
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
            getInterfaceId : function () { return this.interfaceId++; }, // For UI functions
            startMouse:undefined,
        };
        function mouseMove(e) {
            //console.log(e)
            var t = e.type, m = mouse;
            m.lx = e.offsetX; m.ly = e.offsetY;
            m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; 
            m.alt = e.altKey;m.shift = e.shiftKey;m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
            if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") {m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail;}
            if (canvasMouseCallBack) { canvasMouseCallBack(m.x, m.y); }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        function startMouse(element){
            if(element === undefined){
                element = document;
            }
            "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",").forEach(
            function(n){element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);});
            element.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
        }
        mouse.mouseStart = startMouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    demoMouse.mouseStart(element);
    return demoMouse;
}
/** MouseFullDemo.js end **/


var cellSize = 70;
var createImage=function(w,h){
    var i=document.createElement("canvas");
    i.width=w;
    i.height=h;
    i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");
    return i;
}
var drawCircle= function(img,x,y,r,col,colB,col1,width){
    var c = img.ctx;
    var g;
    c.lineWidth = width;
    c.strokeStyle = col1;
    g = c.createRadialGradient(x,y,1,x,y,r);
    g.addColorStop(0,col);
    g.addColorStop(1,colB);
    c.fillStyle = g;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x,y,r-width*3,0,Math.PI*2);
    c.fill();

    c.strokeStyle = col1;
    c.fillStyle = col1;
    c.fillRect(x,y-width,r,width*2)
    c.fillStyle = col;
    c.fillRect(x+width,y-width/2,r,width)
}
var drawCircleO= function(img,x,y,r,col,colB,col1,width){
    var c = img.ctx;
    var g = c.createRadialGradient(x+r*0.21,y+r*0.21,r*0.7,x+r*0.21,y+r*0.21,r);
    g.addColorStop(0,"black");
    g.addColorStop(1,"rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    c.fillStyle = g;
    c.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x+r*0.21,y+r*0.21,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    c.fill();
    c.globalAlpha = 1;
    var g = c.createRadialGradient(x*0.3,y*0.3,r*0.5,x*0.3,y*0.3,r);
    g.addColorStop(0,col);
    g.addColorStop(1,colB);
    c.lineWidth = width;
    c.strokeStyle = col1;
    c.fillStyle = g;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x,y,r-width,0,Math.PI*2);
    c.stroke();
    c.fill();
}
// draws radial marks with miner markes 
// len,col and width are arrays
var drawCircleMarks= function(img,x,y,r,start,end,col,width,length,number,miner){
    var i,vx,vy,count,style,len;
    var c = img.ctx;
    var step = (end-start)/number;
    count = 0;

    end += step/2; // add to end to account for floating point rounding error
    for(i = start; i <= end; i+= step){
        vx = Math.cos(i);
        vy = Math.sin(i);
        if(count % miner === 0){
            style = 0;
        }else{
            style = 1;
        }
        c.strokeStyle = col[style];
        c.lineWidth = width[style];
        len = length[style];
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(vx*r+x,vy*r+y);
        c.lineTo(vx*(r+len)+x,vy*(r+len)+y);
        c.stroke();
        count += 1;

    }
}

var defaultMap = {
    number:function(num,def){
        if( isNaN(num) ){
            return def
        }
        return Number(num);
    },
    colour:function(col,def){
        // no much code for demo so removed
        if(col === undefined || typeof col !== "string"){
            return def;
        }
        return col;
    },
    "ticks":{
        validate:function(val){
            return val===undefined?true:val?true:false;
        },
    },
    "type":{
        validate:function(val){
            switch (val) {
                case "dial":
                case "horizontal-slider":
                    return val;
            }
            return undefined
        }
    },
    "min":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0);
        }
    },
    "max":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,100);
        }
    },
    "drag":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0.4);
        }
    },    
    "reflect":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0.2);
        }
    },
    "accel":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0.4);
        }
    },
    "value":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0);
        }
    },
    "tick-color":{
        validate:function(val){
            
        }
    },
    "decimals":{
        validate:function(val){
            return defaultMap.number(val,0);
        }
    },
    "display":{
        validate:function(val){
            if(val === null || val === undefined || typeof val !== "string"){
                return undefined;
            }
            return document.querySelector(val);
        }
    }
}

// validates user defined DOM attribute
function getSafeAttribute(element,name){
    var val,def;
    if(name === undefined){
        return undefined;
    }
    def = defaultMap[name];
    if(def === undefined){ // unknown attribute 
        if(element.attributes["data-"+name]){
            return element.attributes["data-"+name].value;
        }
        return undefined
    }
    if(element.attributes["data-"+name]){
        val = element.attributes["data-"+name].value;
    }
    return def.validate(val);
}
// Custom user control
// Warning this can return a undefined control
function Control(element,owner){
    var dialUpdate,drawFunc,w,h,nob,back,mouse,minSize,canvas,chaser,dragging,dragX,dragY,dragV,realValue,startP,endP,lastVal,reflect,drag,accel;
    var dialUpdate = function(){
        var unitPos = (this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min);
        canvas.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        canvas.ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        canvas.ctx.drawImage(back,0,0);
        canvas.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,back.width/2,back.height/2);
        canvas.ctx.rotate(unitPos *(endP-startP)+startP);
        canvas.ctx.drawImage(nob,-nob.width/2,-nob.height/2);
    }

    if(element === undefined){ // To my UNI mentor with love.. LOL
         return undefined; 
    }
    this.type = getSafeAttribute(element,"type");
    if(this.type === undefined){
        return undefined;     // this is a non standared contrutor return
    }
    
    this.owner = owner; // expose owner
    // exposed properties
    this.min = getSafeAttribute(element,"min");
    this.max = getSafeAttribute(element,"max");
    this.ticks = getSafeAttribute(element,"ticks");
    this.tickColor = getSafeAttribute(element,"tick-color");
    this.value = realValue = getSafeAttribute(element,"value");

    this.display = getSafeAttribute(element,"display");
    if(this.display){
        var decimals  = getSafeAttribute(element,"decimals");
    }
    drag = getSafeAttribute(element,"drag");
    accel = getSafeAttribute(element,"accel");  
    reflect = getSafeAttribute(element,"reflect");;
    chaser = new Inertia(this.min,this.max,accel,drag,reflect);
    
    w = element.offsetWidth;
    h = element.offsetHeight;

    canvas = createImage(w,h);
    minSize = Math.min(w,h);
    mouse = createMouse(element);
    if(this.type === "dial"){
        nob = createImage(minSize*(3/4),minSize*(3/4));
        drawCircle(nob,minSize*(3/4)*(1/2),minSize*(3/4)*(1/2),minSize*(3/4)*(1/2),"white","#CCC","black",3);
        back = createImage(minSize,minSize);
        startP = Math.PI*(3/4);
        endP = Math.PI*(9/4);
        drawCircleMarks(
            back,
            minSize/2,
            minSize/2,
            minSize/3,
            startP,
            endP,
            ["black","#666"],
            [2,1],
            [minSize*(1/4),minSize*(1/9)],
            16,
            4
        );
        drawCircleO(back,minSize*(1/2),minSize*(1/2),minSize*(3/4)*(1/2),"white","#aaa","black",3);        
        drawFunc = dialUpdate.bind(this);
    }
    element.appendChild(canvas);
    this.active = true;
    this.resetChaser = function(min,max,accel1,drag1,reflect1){
        this.min = min===null?this.min:min;
        this.max = max===null?this.max:max;
        drag = drag1===null?drag:drag1;
        accel = accel1===null?accel:accel1;
        reflect = reflect1===null?reflect:reflect1;
        chaser = new Inertia(this.min,this.max,accel,drag,reflect);
        
        chaser.setValue(this.value);
        drawFunc();
    }
    this.update = function(){
        var inVal;
        if(mouse.over){
            element.style.cursor = "drag_ew";
        }
        if((this.owner.mouse.buttonRaw&1) === 1 && !dragging && mouse.over && this.owner.draggingID === -1){
            dragX = this.owner.mouse.x - (mouse.lx-w/2);
            dragY = this.owner.mouse.y - (mouse.ly-h/2);
            dragging = true;
            this.owner.draggingID = this.ID;
        }else
        if(this.owner.draggingID === this.ID && ((this.owner.mouse.buttonRaw&1) === 1 || (this.owner.mouse.buttonRaw&1) === 0) && dragging){
            inVal = (Math.atan2(this.owner.mouse.y-dragY,this.owner.mouse.x-dragX)+Math.PI*2);
            if(inVal > Math.PI*0.5+Math.PI*2){
                 inVal -= Math.PI*2;
            }
            realValue = inVal;
            realValue = ((realValue-startP)/(endP-startP))*(this.max-this.min)+this.min;
            if((this.owner.mouse.buttonRaw&1) === 0){
                dragging = false;  
                this.owner.draggingID = -1;
            }
        }
        realValue = Math.min(this.max,Math.max(this.min,realValue));
        this.value = chaser.update(realValue);
        
        if(!chaser.quiet){
            drawFunc();
            if(this.display){
                this.display.textContent = realValue.toFixed(decimals);
            }
            if(this.onchange !== undefined && typeof this.onchange === "function"){
                this.onchange({value:realValue,target:element,control:this});
            }
        }
    }
    // force chaser to wake up
    chaser.setValue(this.value);
    drawFunc();
    element.control = this;
}

// find and create controllers
function Controllers(name){
    var controls, elems, i, control, e;
    var ID = 0;
    controls = [];
    elems = document.querySelectorAll("."+name);
    for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
        e = elems[i];
        control = new Control(e,this);
        control.ID = ID++;
        if(control !== undefined){
            controls.push(control);
        }
    }
    this.update = function(){
        controls.forEach(function(cont){
            cont.update();
        })
    }
    this.mouse = createMouse(document);
    this.draggingID = -1;
}

// get elements to play with the large control
var c = new Controllers("testControl");
var drag = document.getElementById("dragSetting");
var accel = document.getElementById("accelSetting");
var reflect = document.getElementById("reflectSetting");
var bigDial = document.getElementById("bigDial");
var bigDialt = document.getElementById("bigDialText");
// callback for large controller
function changeBigDial(e){
    bigDial.control.resetChaser(null,null,drag.control.value,accel.control.value,reflect.control.value);
    if(accel.control.value === 0 || drag.control.value === 0){
        var str = "Can no move as Drag and/or Acceleration is Zero";
    }else{
        var str  = "A:"+ accel.control.value.toFixed(3);
        str += "D:"+ drag.control.value.toFixed(3);
        str += "R:-"+ reflect.control.value.toFixed(3);
    }
    bigDialt.textContent = str;
}
// set callbacks
drag.control.onchange = changeBigDial;
accel.control.onchange = changeBigDial;
reflect.control.onchange = changeBigDial;

// Update all controls
function update(){
    c.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

```css
.testControl {
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.big {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    
}
.demo {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"><h3> Examples of variouse Drag and Acceleration settings</h3>
<p>Click on the control to change the setting. Click drag to adjust setting. The first two rows are preset. <b>D</b> and <b>A</b> above the control are the <b>D</b>rag and <b>A</b>cceleration settings for the control under it.</p>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.1" data-accel="0.9" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.1 <b>A</b>:0.9</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.2" data-accel="0.8" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.2 <b>A</b>:0.8</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.3" data-accel="0.7" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.3 <b>A</b>:0.7</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.4" data-accel="0.6" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.4 <b>A</b>:0.6</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.5" data-accel="0.5" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.5 <b>A</b>:0.5</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.6" data-accel="0.4" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.6 <b>A</b>:0.4</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.7" data-accel="0.3" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.7 <b>A</b>:0.3</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.8" data-accel="0.2" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.8 <b>A</b>:0.2</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.9" data-accel="0.1" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.9 <b>A</b>:0.1</span><br>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.9" data-accel="0.9" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.9 <b>A</b>:0.9</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.8" data-accel="0.8" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.8 <b>A</b>:0.8</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.7" data-accel="0.7" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.7 <b>A</b>:0.7</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.6" data-accel="0.6" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.6 <b>A</b>:0.6</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.5" data-accel="0.5" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.5 <b>A</b>:0.5</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.4" data-accel="0.4" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.4 <b>A</b>:0.4</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.3" data-accel="0.3" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.3 <b>A</b>:0.3</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.2" data-accel="0.2" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.2 <b>A</b>:0.2</span>
<span class="testControl" data-drag="0.1" data-accel="0.1" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><b>D</b>:0.1 <b>A</b>:0.1</span><br>
<h3>The following 3 dials control the inertia setting of the large dial</h3>
<span class="testControl" id="dragSetting" data-value="0" data-display="#display-drag" data-decimals="3" data-min="0" data-max="1"  data-type = "dial" >Drag <span id="display-drag">0.000</span></span>
<span class="testControl" id="accelSetting" data-value="0" data-display="#display-accel" data-decimals="3" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-type = "dial" >Accel <span id="display-accel">0.000</span></span>
<span class="testControl" id="reflectSetting" data-value="0" data-display="#display-reflect" data-decimals="3" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-type = "dial" >Reflect <span id="display-reflect">0.000</span></span>
</div>
<div class="demo">
<div class="testControl big" id="bigDial"  data-drag="0.1" data-accel="0.1" data-value="0" data-type = "dial" ><span id="bigDialText">Letf click drag to change</span></div><br>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you for your complete and descriptive answer. I was in sock when I saw you've added the complete code too.

Comment: @Blindman67, your example is really impressive! What's the license of this code? Could you put it on a github? Otherwise, can I do that? Maybe I'll be able to add some tests and export it as JavaScript library.

Comment: @Terite All code on stackoverflow is in the public domain, thus you are most welcome to use the code in whichever way you see fit. I would just ask you provide a link to this answer in both the source and github README.md if you wish to publish. It's not a condition just a request.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/Starglider/pen/LYEELVy/left

```js
let log = function (arg) { console.log(arg); }

let container;
let box;
let debug;
let innertia;

function CursorFollow() {
    log("CursorFollow()");

    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let box = document.getElementById("box");
    let slider = document.getElementById("range");
    let sliderValue = document.getElementById("range-value");
    let debug = document.getElementById("debug");

    let containerX = 0;
    let containerY = 0;
    let limX = 0;
    let limY = 0;

    let inertia = 0.3;

    let cx = 0; // current
    let cy = 0;
    let tx = 0; // target
    let ty = 0;
    let x = 0; // working value
    let y = 0;

    let firstRun = true;

    function init() {

        inertia = parseFloat(slider.value);

        containerX = window.scrollX + container.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        containerY = window.scrollY + container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        limX = container.getBoundingClientRect().width - box.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        limY = container.getBoundingClientRect().height - box.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        cx = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).left);
        cy = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).left);

        slider.addEventListener("change", sliderChangeHandler);
        container.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);

        update();
    }
    // - - - - - -


    function sliderChangeHandler(e){
        inertia = parseFloat(slider.value);
    }
    // - - - - - -


    function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
        // log(e);
        // problem is offsetX&Y goes to zero when mouse doesnt move!
        tx = e.clientX - containerX;
        ty = e.clientY - containerY;

        if (tx > limX){
            tx = limX;
        }
        if (ty > limY){
            ty = limY;
        }

    }
    // - - - - - -


    function update() {

        // So we dont have to getComputerStlye in update loop
        if (firstRun){
            firstRun = false;
        } else {
            cx = x;
            cy = y;
        }


        // debug.innerHTML = cx;
        x = inertiaTo(cx,tx,inertia);
        y = inertiaTo(cy,ty,inertia);

        box.style.left = x + "px";
        box.style.top = y + "px";

        debug.innerHTML = "x:" + x + " y:" + y;

        sliderValue.innerHTML = "inertia: " + inertia;

        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    // - - - - - -


    function inertiaTo(current,target,amount){
        if (amount==1){
            return target;
        }
        let distToGo = target-current;
        let delta = current + (distToGo * amount);

        if (Math.abs(distToGo) < 0.01){
            distToGo = 0;
            delta = target;
        }

        // debug.innerHTML = distToGo;
        return delta;
    }
    // - - - - - -


    // Constructor simulation
    init();
    // - - - - - -

}





new CursorFollow();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #CC0000;
}


#range-value {
    width: 300px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
}

#range {
    width: 300px;
}

#debug {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    min-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>

<div id="range-value">0</div>
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="0.6" step="0.01" value="0.2"/>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another variable, `betaCumulative`, and adjust its value in small increments like so:

```
if(beta < betaCumulative)betaCumulative += .01;
if(beta > betaCumulative)betaCumulative -= .01;
myTriangle.rotation = betaCumulative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Blindman67's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377481/4421838) answer, I experienced some issues where the Inertia value would infinitely approach the min or max values, leading to ridicolously long decimals.

I'm not equipped to say whether this would pose a performance issue, but I added a `decimals` variable to round the return value to that many decimals, and also limited the delta value to 8 decimals. You can change the default decimal amount by replacing the default value for `decimals` in the class constructor.

```
// Define a Inertia object. Set Answer for details.
// Has methods
// update(input); Called once pre animation frame with input being the value to chase
// setValue(input); Hard sets the chasing value. Not drag or inertia
// Has properties
// value;  The chasing value bounds checked
class Inertia {
  constructor(min, max, acceleration, drag, reflect, decimals = 4) {
    // some may question why the constants, why not use the closure on arguments
    // Reason: Some JS environments will fail to optimise code if the input
    //         arguments change. It may be tempting to extend this Object to
    //         change the min, max or others. I put this here to highlight the
    //         fact that argument closure variables should not be modified
    //         if performance is important.
    const ac = acceleration; // set constants
    const dr = drag;
    const minV = min;
    const maxV = max;
    const ref = -Math.abs(reflect); // ensure a negative. Why? because I always forget this is a negative.
    this.value = min;
    var delta = 0;

    this.update = function (input) {
      delta += (input - this.value) * ac;
      delta *= dr;
      this.value += delta;
      this.value = Math.round(this.value * Math.pow(10, 8)) / Math.pow(10, 8);
      if (this.value < minV) {
        this.value = minV;
        if (delta < 0) {
          delta *= ref;
        }
      } else if (this.value > maxV) {
        this.value = maxV;
        if (delta > 0) {
          delta *= ref;
        }
      }
      return (
        Math.round(this.value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals)
      );
    };
    // this move the value to the required value without any inertial or drag
    // is bound checked
    this.setValue = function (input) {
      delta = 0;
      this.value = Math.min(maxV, Math.min(minV, input));
      return this.value;
    };

    // this gets the value, rounded to the decimals specified in the function call
    this.getValue = function () {
      return (
        Math.round(this.value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals)
      );
    };
  }
}
```